# TFileStream.Seek beyond end of file

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2007

we just came across a peculiar behaviour of the TFileStream.Seek (actually that method is inherited from THandleStream) in Delphi 2007:

You can seek beyond the end of file without an error and after the seek you can even read from the file without an error.

The code does basically just call the Windows API function SetFilePointer and seems to do proper error handling. Can somebody explain what's happening here?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300938/delphi-tfilestream-seek-how-to-check-for-invalid-seek-offset

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365541%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> It is not an error to set a file
>   pointer to a position beyond the end
>   of the file. The size of the file does
>   not increase until you call the
>   SetEndOfFile, WriteFile, or
>   WriteFileEx function. A write
>   operation increases the size of the
>   file to the file pointer position plus
>   the size of the buffer written, which
>   results in the intervening bytes
>   uninitialized.

This is how the file system is designed to work.

Comment: I was two seconds away from posting an identical answer :) I consider it strange though that this behavior also includes files that are open read-only.

Comment: @Ville In that case I guess the error checking occurs when you call `SetEndOfFile` or `WriteFile`. It's probably an optimisation that allows `SetFilePointer` to avoid checking permission rights.

Comment: I would have sworn I read the complete documenation on SetFilePointer on MSDN, but I somehow missed that paragraph. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Afaik this behaviour (seek beyond end, write block there) is needed to support NTFS sparse files.